# Use Streaming Online Video/Live As Source In OBS Studio

Tags: streaming, live, obs

Is this possible?

Use others or your own Facebook or YouTube live stream as source in obs or any broadcast software and then broadcast it on another page or channel.

Comment: Yes it is.. create a scene with your fullscreen browser and the video you want

Answer (score 7):

This would be possible using OBS's `BrowserSource`.

First, find the embed code for the stream (in YouTube you can click "Share" and then "Embed"). Find the `src=""` and copy the URL that's inside the quotes. In OBS, create a new `Browser`. Paste the previously copied URL into the `URL` field, and set the `Width` and `Height` to your canvas size (or your preferred size).

If you need to press a play button, you can right-click the Browser and click `Interact`.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this is to make a .html file with this content:

```
<iframe width="1920" height="1080"src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/[VIDEO ID]?&autoplay=1"frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

replacing [VIDEO ID] with the youtube video id, then going into OBS and adding it as a local browser. Then it'll work a lot faster as it just loads the files you want.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old, but I just figured it out, since the "embed" thing didn't work for me. Youtube blocks the view all the time with suggestions to log in or accept cookie messages.

Here is what you can do:

1. Open VLC locally
2. Go to "Open Network"
3. Paste your Youtube Video link
   (VLC will convert the URL into a link to a playable video stream)
4. Save the playlist as .m3u file
5. Open the .m3u file in a text editor
6. Copy the line starting with "https://"
7. Open OBS
8. Add a "VLC Video Source"
9. Go to "playlist" and hit "+"
10. Paste the URL copied from VLC

Voilá! The video plays in the VLC source.

Comment: I would love to know why this got downvoted, it seems like a reasonable suggestion to me. Are there problems with this strategy?